# Can I write an application in Qt that runs with Gnome?

Tags: qt, gnome

I want to write a program for linux with Qt.

I know KDE is coded in Qt and Gnome isn't. Is it still possible to write a program in Qt for Gnome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If you write a Qt app, it *will* run fine under GNOME, provided that the user has the Qt libraries installed (or, and this is often better, you ship them with your app)
2. Your Qt app will look *almost* native under GNOME if you make it use QGtkStyle as its widgetstyle (this is done via QApplication::setStyle). This means the app won't look ugly or foreign under GNOME (except for some very small details)

Answer (score 1):

Qt applications run just fine on Gnome. You just need to install the appropriate libraries.

Comment: Great, i thought that KDE is created by QT and i can't code for other desktop environment.